# How do I make my Fragment layout fit under the tabs created in main Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem which seems to have a different solution everytime it is asked, and causing me great distress. I have tried to use the solutions in other SO questions, but none worked.
I have an Activity from which initializes a ViewPager, a toolbar and a TabLayout. There are two tabs, both of which are implemented using fragments. The problem is
that my fragment is layed out with a spinner, a recycler view, a button and a textfield. Of these widgets, only the recyclerView shows up with the first two items missing,
forcing me to believe the Spinner is hidden just behind my AppLayoutBar, and the textField and buttons are below the screen. My question is, how do I get the layout
of my fragment to appear in the visible part of the screen below the tabs?  Below are the Layout files for both fragment and main activity

Fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
   >

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:entries="@array/status"
        >
    </Spinner>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.75"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="@string/goal_edit_text_hint"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:maxLines="5"
        android:minLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/addButton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/add_button_text"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/math"
        android:id="@+id/addButton" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="612dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Detail Tutorial [Have a look At](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

> Dear I can understand your problem and I have a solution for you that will work perfectly. I'm giving complete piece of code that will solve your issue.

**Step - 1**: Paste this XML in your `Main Activity` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.broadpeakit.hmehmood.company.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.CustonActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Step 2** - Crate another layout with named `content_home`. and paste this code there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.broadpeakit.hmehmood.company.HomeActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_home">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fl_testing"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"></FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 3** - Now Create another `layout` with name `viewPager_fragment` that will contain your view pager with tabs and we'll inflate this layout later.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/gray"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/red"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tabs"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Step 4** - Now create a class with name `viewPagerFragment` and `extends` it with `Fragment`. we'll inflate this `Fragment` later in your Main Activity.

```
public class viewPagerFragment  extends Fragment {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    TabsTestFragment1 tabsTestFragment1;
    TabsTestFragment2 tabsTestFragment2;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewPager_fragment, container, false);
}


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ((HomeActivity)getActivity()).updateDrawerIcon();

        tabsTestFragment1 = new TabsTestFragment1();
        tabsTestFragment2 = new TabsTestFragment1();

        viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
    public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(tabsTestFragment1, "Tab 1");
        adapter.addFragment(tabsTestFragment2, "Tab 2");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

}
```

**Step 5** - Now place this code in `onCreate` of your `Main Activity`.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN).replace(R.id.fl_testing, new viewPagerFragment()).commit();
```

Now you are good to **RUN** your code. Get back to me if you have any issue later. Also mark this issue as solved if you are able to solve your issue using this code. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your Main Activity with this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```